# Grails Mapping http://localhost:8080

Tags: grails, mapping

Is it possible to map `http://localhost:8080/controller/action` to something like `http://myApp/controller/action` with Grails mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either specify a local domain in /etc/hosts(or equivalent for your OS) or buy a domain from a provider. It has nothing to do with Grails. With URL mappings you only control what's after your application URL.